# android is there Bluetooth receiver like sms?

Tags: android, bluetooth

hello everyone i face a real problem i have an arduino device that sends text information via bluetooth and i want to receive this text on my android phone but i want to check the ((text))before any reaction

is there any way to do that like SMS ((BroadcastReceiver))

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how exactly to do that. But in the same way you use Receiver for SMS you can use Receiver for Bluetooth.

Register receiver (Manifest or in code)

```
registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

And define the receiver

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        String name;
            name = device.getName();

        }
    }
};
```

I suppose : with the communication you can catch a different pram in intent that gives to you the text.

if you want some examples take a look. 
http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/scan-bluetooth-devices.html  AND 
http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/